# How insert a array into a table in postgresql function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I received a jsonb in a function and I need insert in distincs rows

```
{
"client":"12345678",
"documents": ["0ca15b8f-c7b3-4a36-931b-e3faf6eaa571",
            "597c18e5-10d4-4656-a256-108e9674c3aa",
            "68056dfc-9799-4baf-b26b-4336586a5a2e"]
}
```

Currently I'm testing with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tribal.fn_add_documents(spec jsonb)
 RETURNS json
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    begin
        INSERT INTO documents (id_document) 
            SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(spec->'documents'::json);
        return ('{"code" : "200"}'::jsonb);
    END;
$function$;
```

I hope a result like

| client | id_document |
| --- | --- |
| 12345678 | 0ca15b8f-c7b3-4a36-931b-e3faf6eaa571 |
| 12345678 | 597c18e5-10d4-4656-a256-108e9674c3aa |
| 12345678 | 68056dfc-9799-4baf-b26b-4336586a5a2e |

**id_document is a UUID type**

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

I am not sure I got your question right, but if you just want to unnest the jsonb array and repeat the client id just do the following

```
SELECT 
  spec->>'client' AS client,
  (jsonb_array_elements(spec->'documents')->>0)::uuid AS id_document
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2f52c37e19fe8002bdafb52367b2c52a)

```
WITH j (spec) AS ( VALUES
  ('{"client":"12345678",
  "documents": ["0ca15b8f-c7b3-4a36-931b-e3faf6eaa571",
            "597c18e5-10d4-4656-a256-108e9674c3aa",
            "68056dfc-9799-4baf-b26b-4336586a5a2e"]
  }'::jsonb)
)
SELECT 
  spec->>'client' AS client,
  (jsonb_array_elements(spec->'documents')->>0)::uuid AS id_document
FROM j;

  client  |             id_document              
----------+--------------------------------------
 12345678 | 0ca15b8f-c7b3-4a36-931b-e3faf6eaa571
 12345678 | 597c18e5-10d4-4656-a256-108e9674c3aa
 12345678 | 68056dfc-9799-4baf-b26b-4336586a5a2e
```

As you can see, there is no need to write a PL/pgSQL function for that, but in case must, this is how it would look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tribal.fn_add_documents(spec jsonb)
 RETURNS json
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO documents (client,id_document) 
  SELECT spec->>'client',
  (jsonb_array_elements(spec->'documents')->>0)::uuid;
RETURN('{"code" : "200"}'::jsonb);
END; $$;
```

Comment: I tried with your code and I don't received any error, but data don't save. It's necesary a "confirm"? For instance: in Python after set a "insert into" is necessary a "conn.commit". Thanks!

Comment: @HendrisVs how are you calling the function?

Comment: Sorry for previous question.  The code works ok, thanks JIm!!

Comment: @HendrisVs nice it works. If it answers your question, consider accepting the and upvoting the answer, so that other users also get to profit from it. cheers